# Correspondence and bijective correspondence between two sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let$A$ and $B$ be two sets. When we say there is a bijective correspondence between $A$ and $B$, it means there is a bijective map between them.

In some texts, to prove there is a correspondence between $A$ and $B$, just show that correspondence to every element of $A$ there is an element in $B$ and conversely. While I think we should prove that there is a well-defined surjective map from $A$ onto $B$. Am I right? Please explain it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're thinking of the [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem): If there is an injective map from $A$ to $B$, and an injective map from $B$ to $A$, then there exists a bijective correpondence between $A$ and $B$.

It is necessary that the given maps be injective; otherwise, any two non-empty sets would satisfy the conditions, because you could map every element in one set to a single element in the other.

You can think of what's going on in terms of cardinality, or sizes of the sets. If we have an injection $A\to B$, then we know that $|A|\le |B|$. If we also have an injection $B\to A$, then we know that $|B|\le |A|$. Having both of those inequalities implies that $A$ and $B$ actually have the same cardinality. What I've just said is not a proof of Schröder–Bernstein, though. In fact, it's the other way around.

The proof of Schröder–Bernstein is interesting, and not completely trivial. I recommend the link above, for learning more about it.

Comment: For bijective correspondence, I do not have any problem. My question is about the existence of a correspondence which is not necessarily one-to-one.

Comment: In fact, to check there is a correspondence between two sets is sufficient to prove that correspondence to $a\in A$  there is $b\in B$ which is computed based on  $a$ and conversely.

Comment: If the mappings aren't one-to-one, then you can't conclude anything. What if $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, and mappings in both directions are given by $x\mapsto |x|/x$?